# Valgrind showing over 200 allocs for a hello world program on OS X?

Tags: c, macos, valgrind

I wrote a linked list in C today at work on a Linux machine and everything checked out in Valgrind. Then I ran the same test (a handful of pushes and then deleting the list) at home on OS X and got a crazy amount of allocs.

```
==4344== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4344==     in use at exit: 26,262 bytes in 187 blocks
==4344==   total heap usage: 267 allocs, 80 frees, 32,374 bytes allocated
==4344== 
==4344== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4344==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4344==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4344==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4344==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4344==         suppressed: 26,262 bytes in 187 blocks
==4344== 
==4344== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4344== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I know the code is fine and doesn't have any leaks. So I just commented out the list test and compiled with only `printf("test\n");` in the main, and it showed 263 allocs with 76 frees (I had 4 intentional allocs in the list test). Why am I getting so many allocs on OS X? Is this just something the OS did? I don't understand why I'd have 263 allocs when I just did a printf...

Answer (score 0):

OS X has a very bad architecture. Because `libdl`, `libdyld`, `libm`, `libc` and some other libraries are "packed" into `libSystem`, all of them are initialized when the library is loaded. Most of them come from dyld. Dyld is written in C and C++, that's why C++ part may push up number of allocs.

This is only Apple thing, not OS X thing. I have written an alternate C library. It does not have many "not-needed allocs".

---

Also, allocs are caused by opening `FILE *`s. Note that 3 streams (`stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`) are initialized on run.

Comment: At least on Linux, stdio-streams (including `stdin/stdout`) `mmap()` their buffers on first use, not on program startup.

Answer (score 0):

Valgrind support on OS X is currently being actively worked on. Your best approach is to ensure you are using a SVN trunk build, and update frequently.

The errors Valgrind is reporting to you are present within the OS X system libraries. These are not the fault of your program, but because even simple programs including these system libraries Valgrind continues to pick them up. Suppressions within Valgrind trunk are continually being updated to catch these issues, allowing you to focus on the real problems that may be present within your code.

The following commands will allow you to use Valgrind trunk, if you're not already:

```
svn co svn://svn.valgrind.org/valgrind/trunk valgrind
cd valgrind
./autogen.sh
./configure
make -j4
sudo make install
```

*Full disclosure: I'm one of the Valgrind developers who contributed patches to support OS X 10.11*